# Convert Go rune to string

Tags: string, go, rune

I am trying to convert `s := '{"selector:"{"Status":"open"}"}'` to type `string`, as I need to pass this as an argument to a query using `GetQueryResult()`.

I have tried `UnescapeString`, it only accepts string as argument:

```
fmt.Println("args " ,html.UnescapeString(s)
```

but `s` is a Go `rune`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[String literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals)

[Rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals)

---

Use `string` raw literal back quotes, not `rune` literal single quotes.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := `{"selector:"{"Status":"open"}"}`
    fmt.Printf("type %T: %s", s, s)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lGARb35VHTv

Output:

```
type string: {"selector:"{"Status":"open"}"}
```